# Редактировать файлы в docroot от имени другого пользователя

Tags: apache, unix, chmod

Имеется сайт по категории /var/www/public_html содержимому выставлены права apache owner/group www-data, вопрос как задать так-же полные права на другого пользователя, я как понимаю что не достаточно просто этого пользователя тоже поместить в группу www-data? (Вариант с chmod 777 - не предлагать).

Comment: пожалуй, наиболее логичный и простой в реализации вариант: обслуживать данный сайт не от имени пользователя `www-data/apache`, а от имени того пользователя, который вам требуется (с соответствующим изменением принадлежности файлов/каталогов).

Comment: то есть сделать так чтоб Owner был я, а Group была www-data? ) мне бы саму логику понять, и главное чтоб для работы апача всего хватало

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. наиболее простой и логичный вариант: обслуживать данный сайт не от имени пользователя `www-data`/`apache`/т.п., а от имени того пользователя, который вам требуется (с соответствующим изменением принадлежности файлов/каталогов).
2. более сложный (в некоторых отношениях) и не всегда удобный вариант: воспользоваться программой *bindfs* (входит в одноимённый пакет в популярных дистрибутивах), которая с помощью интерфейса [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) умеет монтировать каталог в другое место, подменяя при этом принадлежность и права на входящие в него файлы/каталоги.

   пример (для его работы необходимо раскомментировать строку, содержащую `user_allow_other` в файле `/etc/fuse.conf`):

   1. создадим от имени пользователя `www-data` каталог `1` и внутри него `файл1`:

      ```
      $ sudo -u www-data mkdir 1
      $ sudo -u www-data touch 1/файл1
      ```

      это будет наш «исходный» каталог. вот так выглядят права и принадлежность:

      ```
      $ tree -up
      .
      └── [drwxr-xr-x www-data]  1
          └── [-rw-r--r-- www-data]  файл1
      ```
   2. создадим от имени того же пользователя каталог `2`, который будет «рабочим»:

      ```
      $ sudo -u www-data mkdir 2
      ```
   3. и примонтируем от имени того же пользователя каталог `1` в каталог `2`, указав, что владельцем файлов/каталогов внутри `2` будет `user`:

      ```
      $ sudo -u www-data bindfs -u user 1 2
      ```
   4. видим, что каталог `2` и его содержимое принадлежит пользователю `user`:

      ```
      $ tree -up
      .
      ├── [drwxr-xr-x www-data]  1
      │   └── [-rw-r--r-- www-data]  файл1
      └── [drwxr-xr-x user    ]  2
          └── [-rw-r--r-- user    ]  файл1
      ```
   5. теперь от имени пользователя `user` удалим `2/файл1` и создадим `2/файл2`:

      ```
      $ sudo -u user rm 2/файл1
      $ sudo -u user touch 2/файл2
      ```
   6. видим, что эти изменения «синхронно» коснулись и содержимого «исходного» каталога `1`:

      ```
      $ tree -up
      .
      ├── [drwxr-xr-x www-data]  1
      │   └── [-rw-r--r-- www-data]  файл2
      └── [drwxr-xr-x user    ]  2
          └── [-rw-r--r-- user    ]  файл2
      ```

      причём обратите внимание, что новый `1/файл2` принадлежит пользователю `www-data`. это произошло потому, что именно от его имени мы выполняли программу *bindfs*. если бы выполняли от имени пользователя `root`, то он и стал бы владельцем файла.
   7. не забываем отмонтировать каталог `2` (от имени того же пользователя, который монтировал):

      ```
      $ sudo -u www-data fusermount -u 2
      ```
3. если файловая система поддерживает [posix acl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL), то можно воспользоваться программой *setfacl*:

   1. смотрим текущий список прав (каталог `1`, внутри него `файл1`):

      ```
      $ getfacl 1/ 1/файл1
      # file: 1/
      # owner: www-data
      # group: www-data
      user::rwx
      group::r-x
      other::r-x

      # file: 1/файл1
      # owner: www-data
      # group: www-data
      user::rw-
      group::r--
      other::r--
      ```
   2. добавим для каталога `1` рекурсивно (`-R`) и с наследованием (`d:` в начале параметра с правами) набор битов `rwx` и для `someuser`, и для `www-data` (чтобы и тот и другой могли создавать файлы/каталоги, и сразу получать на них права `rwx`):

      ```
      $ sudo setfacl -Rm d:u:someuser:rwx,u:someuser:rwx,d:u:www-data:rwx,u:www-data:rwx 1
      ```

      смотрим, что получилось:

      ```
      $ getfacl 1/ 1/файл1
      # file: 1/
      # owner: www-data
      # group: www-data
      user::rwx
      user:www-data:rwx
      user:someuser:rwx
      group::r-x
      mask::rwx
      other::r-x
      default:user::rwx
      default:user:www-data:rwx
      default:user:someuser:rwx
      default:group::r-x
      default:mask::rwx
      default:other::r-x

      # file: 1/файл1
      # owner: www-data
      # group: www-data
      user::rw-
      user:www-data:rwx
      user:someuser:rwx
      group::r--
      mask::rwx
      other::r--
      ```
   3. проверяем, создавая от имени `someuser` каталог `1/2` и файл `1/2/файл2`:

      ```
      $ sudo -u someuser mkdir 1/2
      $ sudo -u someuser touch 1/2/файл2
      ```

      и видим, что, хотя владельцем и является `someuser`, но и у `www-data` имеется (унаследованный) набор прав `rwx`:

      ```
      $ getfacl 1/2 1/2/файл2 
      # file: 1/2
      # owner: someuser
      # group: someuser
      user::rwx
      user:www-data:rwx
      user:someuser:rwx
      group::r-x
      mask::rwx
      other::r-x
      default:user::rwx
      default:user:www-data:rwx
      default:user:someuser:rwx
      default:group::r-x
      default:mask::rwx
      default:other::r-x

      # file: 1/2/файл2
      # owner: someuser
      # group: someuser
      user::rw-
      user:www-data:rwx       #effective:rw-
      user:someuser:rwx       #effective:rw-
      group::r-x              #effective:r--
      mask::rw-
      other::r--
      ```