# Запуск программ от имени текущего пользователя Linux

Tags: linux, доступ

настраиваю локальный сервер и столкнулся с проблемой, текстовые редакторы имеют не достаточно прав для редактирования файлов.

Нужный каталог находится по адресу /var/www/test
Добавил владельца и группу этому каталогу

```
chown www-data: -R /var/www/test 
chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx -R /var/www/test
```

Далее добавляю пользователя user1 в групп www-data и логинюсь в оболочку под этим юзером

Если пробую через терминал отредактировать любой файл в каталоге /var/www/test все прекрасно получается.

Если же запускаю текстовый редактор из рабочего стола например и опять же пытаюсь отредактировать эти файлы, то получаю ошибку "доступ запрещен"

Почему так происходит?

Comment: В рабочем столе тоже user1 и тоже перелогинились?

Comment: да это единственный юзер пк он же админ

Comment: но если добавляю еще пользователя ситауция все такая же, редактировать через терминал от имени конкретного пользователя (ре рут) могу, а если запустить с рабочего стола, то нельзя

Comment: по конкретному вопросу — после изменения групповой принадлежности надо завершить **все** процессы данного пользователя. перезапуск x-сессии тут не всегда помогает — остаются работать какие-нибудь демоны. по неозвученному вопросу — это фактически [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678846/178576)