# Подскажите как работать с правами в linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, yii2

Простите за столь глупый вопрос. Но я только начал осваивать linux и столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при создании нового файла, программа не может с ним работать. К примеру, я создаю новую модель в yii2 и использую ее в контроллере. Но у меня выкидывает ошибка что котроллер не видит этот файл. Пока я не дам файлам разрешение

> chmod 644 файл

Что мне сделать чтобы файлы сразу создавались с нужным разрешением ?

Comment: Тут еще зависит кто файл создал и кто его использует. Может chown сделать на директорию проекта?

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678846/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу исходя из своего опыта написать как обычно делаю я. В первую очередь нужно добавить пользователя, под которым работаешь, в группу `www-data`:

```
$ usermod -a -G www-data username
```

где `username` - имя твоего пользователя. Затем идёшь в папку `/var/www` и даёшь права на папку с твоим проектом (допустим, `myproject`):

```
$ cd /var/www
$ sudo chmod -R 775 myproject
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data myproject
```

здесь мы что сделали - сначала указали, что папка myproject принадлежит пользователю `www-data` и группе `www-data`. Под этим юзером обычно (в твоём случае с Убунтой 100%) работает веб-сервер (и apache2, и nginx). Воот. Права `775` дают возможность юзеру `www-data` и группе `www-data` делать всё что угодно с папкой `myproject` и её содержимым. А до этого мы добавили себя в группу `www-data`.

и всё :) счастье, радость, хорошее настроение