# Linux (Centos 7) как правильно разграничить права на доступ к каталогу?

Tags: linux, centos

Суть проблемы, есть пользователь admin:admin (/home/admin), у него есть каталог с сайтом /home/admin/web/(тут лежит сайт WordPress)

Создал нового пользователя myuser - группу задал admin (myuser:admin)

Права на папку на чтение и запись есть у группы и у пользователя admin.
Сделал символическую ссылку на папку /home/admin/web в /home/myuser

Но если зайти под myuser, то доступа к папке и файлам /home/myuser/web - нет
то есть символическая ссылка отображается, но перейти в нее нельзя (недостаточно прав)

Если зайти под root, то из /home/myuser/web нормально переходит в /home/admin/web

Как можно каталог расшарить для других пользователей? (Структуру изначально делал не я, предполагаю что в папке пользователя общие папки не должны храниться - но это предположение)

пробовал дать доступ через setfacl (ACL), пользоваетль появляется, но ничего не меняется. Пробовал давать все права рекурсивно, но тоже ничего не дало.

Comment: вы просто хотите изменить доступ к каталогу?

Comment: `ls -ld /home/admin` в студию. подозреваю что там 700. тогда нужно нужно `chmod +x /home/admin`. но это хреновая идея, ибо можно будет увидеть лишнее. переделывайте структуру каталогов полностью, без хомяка

Comment: Там 755 :) и даже так, если зайти под другим пользователем, который находится в той же группе, у него по пути /home/admin ничего не отображается. Хотя у каталога /home/admin/web тоже 755. Буду походу переносить сайт в каталог вне /home

Comment: Сайт настраивался через Vesta. Попробовал добавить через нее второй домен. Он также добавился в папку /home/admin/web   Можно ли поменять что-то в этой Vesta, пока остается загадкой...

Comment: [связанный вопрос, практически дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678846/178576)

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
chmod -R 775 /home/admin/web
```

chmod - утилита для работы с правами доступа к файлам и каталогам.

-R - применить уровень доступа ко всем подкаталогам

775 - опции доступа rwxrwxr-x (запрет на изменение только для пользователей не относящимся к группе этого каталога)

Comment: минусовать не буду, но это очень плохое решение: вы даете доступ всем членам группы, не пойми зачем, это не безопасно. проблему решает? да. но сулит другие. плюс, см мой коммент, если `ls -ld /home/admin` 700, то ваше решение не будет работать

Comment: @TotalPusher я понимаю о чём вы, я не понимаю до конца проблемы и цели автора

Comment: у автора скорее всего дефолтные настройки веб-сервера, а они часто ведут в хомяк. нужна коллективная разработка - значит нужно сделать как написал ТС (я про группы), но разместить не в хомяке, а в `/var/www`, например, и поднастроить веб-сервер. в общем, жду ТС