# Как сделать так что бы git создавал файлы от имени пользователя www-data в linux

Tags: linux, git, chmod

Доброго времени суток.

До git pull владельцем всех файлов является пользователь www-data
После git pull владельцем обновлённых файлов является пользователь под которым я зашел в систему

Before pull : file-owner = www-data
After pull  : file-owner = myuser

Мне не хотелось бы менять владельца файла после каждого обновления. Можно ли как-то сказать гиту какой пользователь должен быть владельцем обновлённых файлов?

Comment: похоже, Вы хотите использовать git для деплоя, я прав?

Comment: `sudo -u www-data git pull`

Comment: @KoVadim верно!

Comment: В целом, это очень сильно не рекомендуется делать, не смотря на простоту метода. Да, совет от AlexGlebe вполне рабочий (особенно, если завернуть в какой-нибудь алиас вида `alias deploy='sudo -u www-data git pull'`. Но лучше написать скрипт, который возьмет сорцы через pull, потом их "обработает, запакует и на сервер отправит". Или воспользоваться готовыми CI/CD системами. Но почему не git pull? Он даже Яндекс так делал для деплоя. А потом сорцы ушли лесом:)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/678846/178576 // @KoVadim, а что это за история с «ушедшими лесом сорцами яндекса»?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/70330/