# Не удалось сохранить "script.js": недостаточные разрешения

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

При редактировании в VSCode вылазит ошибка - **Не удалось сохранить "script.js": недостаточные разрешения. Чтобы повторить попытку с правами администратора, выберите "Повторить попытку в режиме Sudo".** [image: Вот какие права у меня на папке проекта]
Вот какие права у меня на папке проекта
В чем проблема? Подскажите решение, пожалуйста

Comment: Ну вы не в домашнюю папку пытаетесь сохранить, естественно через sudo туда нужно писать. Ну или добавьте своего пользователя в группу www-data.

Comment: Вообще сам vscode предлагает повторить с sudo, просто нажмите "Повторить попытку в режиме Sudo"

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Редактировать файлы в docroot от имени другого пользователя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678846/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-docroot-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod -R g+rwX /var/www

Comment: Благодарю, помогло

Answer (score -1):

По консоли видно, что у тебя нет прав для обычного пользователя на запись в файл, поэтому ты и не можешь сохранить. Чтобы исправить проблемы надо добавить права на запись. Один из способов:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 *
```

Comment: минус за вредный совет.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin почему вредный?

Comment: @milenao, потому что это предложение дать возможность изменять/удалять файлы/каталоги **любому** пользователю системы. причём **вместо** предложения исправить ту ситуацию, которую наворотил в своей системе задавший вопрос.